# Wrapping content in anchor tags with CKEditor

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I am trying to **wrap a block of HTML content** in an  tag in a Drupal 8 installation:

```
<a href="/link"><h2>Link 1</h2><h3>Subheader link 1</h3></a>
```

**CKEditor changes it** to:

```
<h2><a href="/link">Link 1</a></h2><h3><a href="/link">Subheader link 1</a></h3>
```

The **Limit allowed HTML tags** I have set are:

```
<div class id> <p class id> <img class id> <a href hreflang class id> <em> <strong> <cite class id> <blockquote cite cla> <code> <ul type class id> <ol start type class id> <li class id> <dl class id> <dt class id> <dd> <h2 class id> <h3 class id> <h4 class id> <h5 class id> <h6 class id> <s> <sup> <sub> <img src alt data-entity-type data-entity-uuid data-align data-caption class id> <table class id> <caption class id> <tbody class id> <thead class id> <tfoot class id> <th class id> <td class id> <tr class id> <hr class id> <p class id> <h1 class id> <pre class id><section class id><header class id> <a div> <a span>
```

How can I wrap content in an anchor tag with CKEditor?

Comment: That's a CKEditor thing (it doesn't have an HTML5 DTD, so doesn't understand that links can now wrap block level elements). See [this issue](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7961) for resolutions. I think you'll need `CKEDITOR.dtd.a.h2 = 1;` and `CKEDITOR.dtd.a.h3 = 1;`

Comment: @Clive but as it says in the 10th comment, there might be a way to allow it as extra allowed content. How can this be achieved in Drupal 8?

Comment: @Clive I didn't see what you said about "CKEDITOR.dtd.a.h2", where can I include this settings in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution. As @Clive said CKEDITOR.dtd.a.h2 = 1; and CKEDITOR.dtd.a.h3 = 1; is the solution.

These need to be declared in a my_module.module file:

```
function my_module_editor_js_settings_alter(array &$settings) {

  foreach (array_keys($settings['editor']['formats']) as $text_format_id) {
    if ($settings['editor']['formats'][$text_format_id]['editor'] === 'ckeditor') {
        $settings['editor']['formats'][$text_format_id]['editorSettings']['customConfig'] = 
        base_path() . drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/ckeditor_config.js';
}
  }
}
```

And then we create a file ckeditor_config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd['a']['h2'] = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd['a']['h3'] = 1;
```

Doing this we can wrap h2 and h3 elements with an anchor tag and CKEditor is not going to modify it.

Comment: I have the same CKEditor-formatting-issue at the moment.

Can you please tell me more accurate where to put the code mentioned above?

Comment: @tinytree just create a custom module. In the custom module include the php code above, just changing where it says my_module for the name of your module. And also include a file called, ckeditor_config.js in your module folder, including the code that you can see above.

Answer (score 0):

Adding below lines in config.js file has resolved my problem:

```
config.protectedSource.push(/<h1[\s\S]*?\>/g);
config.protectedSource.push(/<\/h1[\s\S]*?\>/g);
config.protectedSource.push(/<h2[\s\S]*?\>/g);
config.protectedSource.push(/<\/h2[\s\S]*?\>/g);
config.protectedSource.push(/<h3[\s\S]*?\>/g);
config.protectedSource.push(/<\/h3[\s\S]*?\>/g);
config.protectedSource.push(/<h4[\s\S]*?\>/g); 
config.protectedSource.push(/<\/h4[\s\S]*?\>/g); 
config.protectedSource.push(/<h5[\s\S]*?\>/g); 
config.protectedSource.push(/<\/h5[\s\S]*?\>/g);
config.protectedSource.push(/<h6[\s\S]*?\>/g); 
config.protectedSource.push(/<\/h6[\s\S]*?\>/g);
```